# Ordered startup of web applications

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I have a two web applications that run on the same Tomcat, but an application depends of the services offered by the other application. Is it possible to set the order in which these applications are started in Tomcat?

Comment: I buy a hosting at gojava.net a week ago, and no one answers me, please answer my request.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Tomcat FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Miscellaneous#Q27):

> What order do webapps start (or how can I change startup order)?
>
> There is no expected startup order. Neither the Servlet spec nor
>   Tomcat define one. You can't rely on the apps starting in any
>   particular order.
>
> While the statement is certainly true, there is a
>   potential "workaround", if you actually have two (or more) apps
>   depending on each other, you may decide to start multiple services in
>   you server.xml: [...]